# "Group By *" in a SQL Server 2008 query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large list of columns in a `Select`.

To group the result I have to get all the items in the select clause and put in the `Group By` clause.

I wonder if there's any easy way to get all the items there for reference in `GROUP BY`, such as a `GROUP BY *`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

The "easy" way is to copy/paste the columns from your `SELECT` into the `GROUP BY`. There's no syntactic short cut in SQL for this.

Comment: ...but there is a UI shortcut for it.  See my answer below for one such...  there might be more, I only know just the one, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're grouping by *all* columns in your `SELECT` clause, surely all you're achieving is to make the results unique, in which case shouldn't you omit the `GROUP BY` clause, and just use `SELECT DISTINCT ...`.

Of course, this then raises the question on why you have duplicate results in your result set anyway, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't really any magic bullets here. You have to list all the columns you are grouping by in the `Group By` clause. You can't use wildcards.

Comment: True about no wildcards.  But not true about magic bullets.  He's just looking for an easier way to write his group-by statement; not avoid it.  If he copies his sql over to query-designer in SSMS, for example, there's a one-click method for automatically generating the group-by statement.

Comment: @kuru kuru na - I guess it depends on your definition of magic bullet. I don't really consider editor tools to be magic bullets since the question was about SQL sntax, moreover, downvoting the answer based on your argument seems pretty overkill to me.

Comment: he's looking for an easy way to make a group-by; he's not *just* interested in a syntactical approach, if you read his question -- he just generally wants to know if there's an easy way to do it.  Your "answer" was that there is no easy way.  It's not a big deal, but you're just wrong in this case.  Didn't mean to hurt your feelings with the vote-down -- I see you got your revenge on my answer though -- good for you.

Comment: @kuru kuru ra - Fair enough. Anyway, I removed the downvote from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not performing any aggregation in your SELECT (sum, avg, count, etc.), they you don't need to have every column in your Group By.

Also -- here's one shortcuts I know of

- Use the Query Designer in SSMS.  R-click the window pane where the tables go, and select 'add group-by'.

Other sql-editors besides SSMS may also have good/better features for stuff like this -- check out TOAD for SQL, etc.

Comment: How is this faster than just a copy and paste of the columns in the select statement into the group by? The copy and paste seems much faster. Having to manually put a check mark beside every column he/she wants to group by could take a long time if there are 40 columns.

Comment: kuru na - I actually tried this myself and with just 10 columns in query designer. It took me nearly 6-7 seconds to click the checkboxes for all those columns. The cut and past of the columns in the select statement took me about 3-4 seconds.  So that's an actual benchmark. Maybe your way is faster for others, but just so you don't think I'm all caught up in ego, I've removed the downvote. I admit I don't use query designer, so hey, maybe this way will work better for some people.

Comment: Actually, you can choose the 'add group-by' after you write your query (so you don't have to use the check-boxes at all -- actually, you don't even have to use the designer much at all, as you can write your query in the normal window, then r-click the window and it will move your sql to the designer) -- so it's literally just 2-clicks: r-click for the menu, then l-click for the option.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joe said in a comment, copy-past is about the easiest it gets. Other than that, there is no built-in way that I know of that will auto-group based on what's being selected.

Answer (score 0):

I drag and drop the columns from the object browser or copy and paste from the select statement.